# What software to create a font?

Tags: windows, windows-7, font-utility

I already have the tools to create pixels or vectors but I have no clue how to generate fonts from them? After some searching I came across a font editing program that cost more then a months rent. A month rent just for lining my characters up is not worth it imho.

So how do I get my characters, pixel and/or vectors, into a font file?

Comment: Have you considered the "private character editor" in Windows/system32?

Comment: @rrirower No I haven't. I just opened it and it's a nice and simple tool but I cannot import anything in there.

Comment: http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html but I don't know if it has import options you need. I've worked in this software many years ago.

Comment: https://icomoon.io is a good free online font creator, it focusses more on icons though if that is what you are after

Answer (score 1):

A google search led me to this tiny piece of software [FontForge.](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/)

### Feature:

- Free
- Open Source
- Good Resource to get started using it
- Cross-Platform
- Supported Types of Fonts

  - OpenType
  - TrueType
  - CID-keyed
  - multi-master and More

Creating Font is not simple task, links below will teach you all about fonts and how to use this software to create fonts.

- [Software Documentation.](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/index.html)

Comment: As the OP asks "So how do I get my characters, pixel and/or vectors, into a font file?" – could you please [edit] your question and point out whether *FontForge* can do that – i.e. importing graphics and convert them to fonts? Thanks!